# Mailchimp - Add styles on the header of a template for responsive

Tags: html, email, header, styles, mailchimp

I'm currently working on a template with Mailchimp.

My email is an HTML file, but I want it to be editable by a client.

So I integer my HTML as a template and not a coded file.

With some text blocks I click on the little button "source" and thanks to that I can use my HTML and the content can be editable.

But I realise that I have a

```
<style> -css- </style>
```

in my header and I don't know where to implement that in my template.
I really need this header because I have style like "webonly" "mobile" and all...

Maybe someone will have an idea, 
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support of Mailchimp give me a solution for my coded file being editable.

In fact you just have to create a coded template with your HTML and to follow the template Language of Mailchimp that's explained here :

https://kb.mailchimp.com/templates/code/create-editable-content-areas-with-mailchimps-template-language

(You have to add mc:edit="nameyouwant" in your TD or else, there's other examples and possibilities in the link above.)

Hope it will help someone one day. :)